# how to write scheme program fast in emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme, racket

```
(define (cube guess x)
    (if (good-enough? guess x)
     guess
     (improve guess x)))
```

I'm using emacs+Racket, but when I write in Racket,it doesn't auto-complete.
I also can't write the Anti-brackets in the same line，like this
`(define (cube guess x) )`. I want to use the 'return' key to make the anti-brackets next line, however the scheme interpreter will compute the expression,then it will be wrong.

then if we write the code in the scheme-mode buffer,it may be some bother, we have to 
select the region,then compute in another buffer

Anyone tell me some better ways?  sorry for my poor English!

Comment: Use DrRacket instead of emacs? http://racket-lang.org/

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you're using an interactive interpreter, and when you hit the "return" key in the middle of a line, it sends the expression to be evaluated rather than allowing you to edit it further. Is this correct? If so, I would encourage you to take a look at Neil Van Dyke's "Quack" package, which (IIRC) is designed to allow you to edit Racket code using emacs.

If you're not married to emacs, then of course I would also suggest trying to use DrRacket.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the scheme interpreter from within Emacs.  This is a good start for writing small functions, but you really want to use a REPL (Read-Eval-Print Loop) workflow.  Thankfully, Emacs has a ready-made scheme REPL built-in, and has been mentioned elsewhere, there are additional modes (like Quack) that enhance the experience.

In the REPL model, you can freely type expressions in the interpreter if you want to try them out, but most of your coding should take place in the file you're writing.  From within that buffer, if you have a scheme interpreter running (M-x run-scheme), then you can send sexps to the interpreter for evaluation without copying manually with C-c C-e.  You can use C-M-x to do the same thing.

You can compile the entire file with C-c C-k, and if you have several expression you want to send together, grab them in a region and use C-c C-r to send the region to the interpreter.

There are several other commands that make transferring your code to interpreter easy; you can read more about them in your REPL session by pressing C-h m to describe the keybindings for your current mode.

Comment: ok,i'm the lazy one.i only select the region and use C-c C-r,but not any other shortcuts，i will learn someothers

Answer (score -1):

What does this code even do ? Are you missing the "if" ? That could be part of the reason the interpreter isn't working.?

(if (good-enough? guess x) guess (improve guess x))

Sorry if I just don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i don't want to talk about the code,i just want to find how to write scheme program fast in emacs

Comment: ok. i don't have a better answer for you as i don't use emacs, but in many programming ide the auto-formatting, auto-complete, etc. depends on you to make good code. if emacs is trying to understand your code to format it and your code is wrong it could have a hard time. (maybe not in this situation, but in some situation)